# Fill the test application form

Tags: java, selenium

Fill the test aplication form

// setp 7  Fill the test aplication form

```
element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//td[@id='firstinput']")).FindElement(By.TagName("input"));
element.SendKeys("test first");
element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/form/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input"));
element.SendKeys("test last");
```

Comment: Please add the html of the table row that you want to set the value. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for more information how to post a Minimal, Reproducible Example as part of your next  question.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @hari Please be clear what support do you need from community? what is your problem statement? what you've tried so far?

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. It's not clear what you're asking or what the problem is.

Comment: This doesn't look like Java. More like C#